# Why does TikZ let me calculate the final angle but not the initial angle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This file runs and does just what I think it should.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
    { \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos #3)},{#5*sin #3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
   \draw (0,0) circle (2);
\foreach \x in {30,60,90}
                         %I want to add a calculation in the following line      
   \centerarc[]($2*(cos \x,sin \x)$)(\x:\x+150:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However that is not what I want to draw.  I want the arcs drawn only inside the circle.  So I would like the initial angle to be `\x+120`.

But when I try to introduce any calculation at all (except +0) on the first argument \x in the expression  `(\x:\x+150:2)` the graphic changes in ways I cannot currently predict.  Specifically the angle I want,  `(\x+120:\x+150:2)` does run and produce a pdf but the graphic is invisible, apparently magnified outside the range of the pdf.

And yet there is no problem calculating `\x+150` for the second argument in the same expression  `(\x:\x+150:2)`.

I would like to understand why this is.  But I guess the main thing is I would like to know how to change it so that I can calculate both the initial and final angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your expression, `cos` and `sin` are functions with one argument that you must enclose in parentheses:

```
\draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5);
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5){
    % Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
    \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5);
  }
  \draw (0,0) circle (2);
  \foreach \x in {30,60,90} {
    % I want to add a calculation in the following line      
    \centerarc[]($2*(cos \x,sin \x)$)(\x+120:\x+150:2);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that two closing parenthesis after `#3` are too much ;-). In fact the problem with original code was just the missing opening parenthesis before both `#3`.

Comment: It's funny that my and your solutions worked with wrong pairs of parenthesis.

Comment: @Ignasi The missing opening parenthesis was very visible ... The closing parenthesis is easily confused with the closing brace and the closing parentheses that follow.

Comment: @Ignasi I put this solution into the actual context of my paper, which made more demands than you see here, and did delimiter checks.  I can tell you it works with many many kinds of wrong parentheses--though different errors become a problem for different inputs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why `\x+120` cannot be used as initial angle in arc definition but here you have two alternative solutions that don't need to use the erroneous syntax.

The first solution consists in `cliping` arcs inside the circle:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
    { \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos #3)},{#5*sin #3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
   \draw (0,0) circle (2);
   \begin{scope}
   \clip (0,0) circle (2);
\foreach \x in {30,60,...,360}
                         %I want to add a calculation in the following line      
   \centerarc[]($2*(cos \x,sin \x)$)(\x:\x+150:2);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the second uses `evaluate` option from `foreach` to calculate `\x+120` as starting angle:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
    { \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos #3)},{#5*sin #3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
   \draw (0,0) circle (2);
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \start using \x+120] in {30,60,...,360}
                         %I want to add a calculation in the following line      
   \centerarc[]($2*(cos \x,sin \x)$)(\start:\x+150:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both solutions produce the same result:

[image]